# How many observations of a variable are missing?

Tags: r

Here is the data that I am using :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl/chmzqmus6bfoaim/climate_clean.csv

I want to know how many observations of the variable `average_temperature_celsius` are missing

But I don't know how to do it, please could you help me

Comment: None: sum(is.na(climate$average_temperature_celsius)) where climate is name of your dataframe

Answer (score 1):

loaded your data in a variable called climate

```
sum(is.na(climate$average_temperature_celsius))
```